# Cannot bind to MessageReciever in Azure ServiceBus function

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have tried every example I can find on the web, and any sort of attempt to do this:

```
 (Message message, string lockToken, MessageReceiver messageReceiver, ILogger log)
```

using either MessageReceiver or the underlying interface, I get this error:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Can't bind parameter 'messageReceiver'
> to type 'Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver'.

I tried setting it up for injecting using the Lazy interface with no luck.

I am using the [ServiceBusTrigger]

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: What version of Functions SDK do you have configured in Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my side it seems no problem.

Please check:

**Function1.cs**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp16
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "str")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log, MessageReceiver messageReceiver, string lockToken)
        {
            messageReceiver.RenewLockAsync(lockToken);
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
        }
    }
}
```

**ProjectName.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus" Version="3.0.0-beta8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.7" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

On my side, MessageReceiver is from namespace `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core`

send message:

```
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient
from azure.servicebus import QueueClient, Message

str = "Endpoint=sb://testbowman.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxx"
queue_client = QueueClient.from_connection_string(str, "myqueue")
msg = Message('Test Message')
queue_client.send(msg)
print('Already send.')
```

return with no error:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, in the end I had to get the names exactly right AND not use BrokeredMessage.  Thanks for your help

Comment: But I dont think messagereciever worked, I needed to use the interface